# SQL query - combine results from 2 SELECT join and result should be all distinct rows

Tags: sql-server

Query #1:

```
Select t1.*
From t1 
Join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

Query #2:

```
Select t1.*
from t1 
join t3 on t1.c2 = t3.c2
```

I would like to combine the results of above 2 select queries and not get any duplicates. I am doing an UNION but it is taking forever to execute

Comment: Please show us sample data from all tables, and the desired output

Comment: UNION ALL includes all records; UNION has the effect of removing duplicates.

Comment: Well, you are using `select *` which means you are returning all columns from both data sets, and you aren't limiting this result set with a where clause so it's returning all rows based on the join condition, and then SQL Server has to dedupe these. If you have a lot of rows, I would expect this to take a long time. You haven't given us the execution plan, DDL, information on the number of columns or rows, indexes, etc. It's taking forever is relative to your environment, memory, NAS / SAN, CPU, MAXDOP and other settings, etc etc etc so what's the real question? Why is it taking forever?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
    from t1
    where 
        exists (
            select t2.c1 
                from t2 
                where 
                  t2.c1 = t1.c1
            )
        or exists (
            select t3.c2 
                from t3 
                where 
                    t3.c2 = t1.c2
            )
```

or, if you need values from t2 and/or t3:

```
select t1.*
    from t1
    left outer join t2 on
        t2.c1 = t1.c1
    left outer join t3 on
        t3.c2 = t1.c2
    where 
         t2.c1 is not null
         or t3.c2 is not null
```

You can try each to see if you get acceptable performance (I don't think you will based on your UNION experience).  If it is slow, you should consider putting a indexes on c1 and c2 in both tables, preferably primary keys on the t2 and t3 tables, and then a non-clustered index on each of c1 and c2 on t1.

Comment: I would like to tell that c1 is only on t2 and not in t3 and c2 is only on t3 and not in t2, would it still work?

Comment: Yeah, I meant C1 in both t1 and t2, and C2 in both t1 and t3.

Answer (score 0):

Amount of time will depend on several aspects of your environment.

Another way to return t1.* would be:

```
select distinct t1.*
  from t1 a
  join t2 b
    on a.c1 = b.c1
  join t3 c
    on a.c2 = c.c2
```

Distinct will sort in tempdb (takes time)